# question related to eigen value of matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ belong to  $M_2(R)$ be a matrix which is not a diagonal matrix.
 If $A^3 = I$, then why is $\operatorname{tr}(A) = -1$ and $\det(A) = 1$?  I am trying to solve it as follows:
let $x$ be an eigenvalue of $A$, then $x^3=1$ implies $x=1,w,w^2$
   and $\operatorname{tr}(A)$ is the sum of the eigenvalues, and $\det(A)$ is the product of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum polynomial of $A$ divides $X^3-1$ but it is not $X-1$ because the matrix is not diagonal.

It must be a proper factor of $X^3-1$, but with *real* coefficients, hence it is $X^2+X+1$, which has degree $2$. Can you say something about the characteristic polynomial of $A$? Can you find the trace and the determinant, once you know the characteristic polynomial?